# Could I use pinia without installing vue?

Tags: pinia

How could i use pinia without vue and vite?

```
 "dependencies": {
    "pinia": "^2.0.11",
    "vite": "^2.7.13",
    "vue": "^3.2.30"
  }
```

I try to use pinia like this:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { useLoginStore } from './src/index.js';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
const pinia = createPinia();
const app = createApp({
  data() {
    return {};
  }
});
app.use(pinia);
const useState = useLoginStore();

console.log(`<<<<01-24 08:52:27>>>>⬇️\n✨`, `useState`, useState);
```

and i use node to run it: `node test`

But it return error

```
Cannot find package '@vue/composition-api' imported from ...\node_modules\vue-demi\lib\index.mjs
```

Answer (score 3):

Assume that your `node test` means running `test.js`, with the content in the file like what you mentioned in the question and no bugs happened in `useLoginStore`, your code should run fine since I can run your example functionally.

For the `Cannot find package` questions, I suggest you delete the `node_modules` directory and reinstall packages by typing `npm install`.

---

If you are asking if Pinia can run without installing Vue, the answer is simply **no**, since Pinia needs to be activated by Vue. You will face the following error if trying to run Pinia without Vue:

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

const useLoginStore = defineStore('login', { /* Options */ });
const useState = useLoginStore();

console.log( useState );
```

```
Error: []: getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
        const pinia = createPinia()
        app.use(pinia)
This will fail in production.
```

References:

- https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-use
- https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/664
- https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1238